# How to know menu items( about or quit) clicked

Tags: cocoa, menubar

I am using notification to get control when menu items clicked...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuChangedItem:) name:NSMenuWillSendActionNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) menuChangedItem :(NSNotification *)inSender
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [inSender userInfo];
    NSMenu *menu = [dict objectForKey:@"MenuItem"];

    NSLog(@"Testing");
}
```

In **menuChangedItem** method, is it possible to know which menu item is clicked(about, quit ,hideall etc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling menu events in cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228642/handling-menu-events-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000267-BBCCFDDI):

> The userInfo dictionary contains the following information:
>   `@"MenuItem"` - The menu item that was chosen.

Try the following out:

```
NSMenuItem *item = [dict objectForKey:@"MenuItem"];
NSLog(@"%@", item);
```